# Sending an email with greek characters doesn't show up correctly (Using HTML,Javascript,PHP)

Tags: php, html, forms, utf-8, mailto

I am trying to make a contact form that opens a new window for confirmation, and from that window, it must open Outlook with the details that I filled in the form. I know that i must use some sort of encoding, but i just can't get it to work.
I modified it from my code, with the actual code you start on contact.html, you type your details then you click submit and form.php opens that shows the data, and it has hidden input boxes that also have the data, so they can show in the mail using mailto. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4TTE.png)

[My form.php code](https://hastebin.com/asoxanatil.bash)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="mailto:abc123@gmail.com" method="post" enctype="x-www-form-urlencoded">
      <table>
 <tr>
          <td>Name:</td>
          <td><input id="name" type="text" name="name" value="Ύθιρτυθριςδ"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Surname:</td>
          <td><input id="surname" type="text" name="surname" value="κσξγΙέκεε"></td>
        </tr>
 <tr>
          <td>Tel:</td>
          <td><input id="tel" type="text" name="tel" value="12345"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>E-mail:</td>
          <td><input id="email" type="text" name="email" value="qwerty@gmail.com"></td>
        </tr>
 <tr>
          <td>Request:</td>
          <td><input id="text" type="text" name="Request" value="ΑΒΓΔεζήθίκ"></td>
        </tr>
       </table>
      <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
   </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this might one of the seldom cases that actually inserting a image of your email might further our understanding of your problem - posting images is 99.9% of the time discouraged...

Comment: i added an image with the steps i take and the email

Comment: Can you show your form.php code?

Comment: I added the code now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script to open an email currently works as follows:

- you click the submit button with the target "mailto:"
- the mail program opens
- the email body gets filled with content of the URL (the URL parameters), hence the cryptic looking email body.

To avoid that, I would suggest to outsource the sending part with a function. 
E.g. when a user clicks the submit button call the function to send an email and build the actual "link" like so: 
`"mailto:you@yourdomain.com?subject=YOURSUBJECT&body=YOURCONTENT"`

Of course you can use string concatenation to build the string, using the values of your form. That should do the trick.